# Disable Opera's autocomplete

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, input, opera

Opera's autocomplete function draws a yellow border around text inputs where it saved data. Is there any way to disable it programmatically?

Here's a picture to illustrate it:
[opera autocomplete http://img709.imageshack.us/img709/4469/opera.png](http://img709.imageshack.us/img709/4469/opera.png)

Comment: it really pisses me off when people do this btw...

Comment: That's not the autocomplete feature, it's the saved passwords feature.

Comment: link is broken. just use stack overflows image upload.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to put the autocomplete="off" attribute on the text inputs ?

Answer (score 1):

Firefox controls these kind of items with several internal `-moz-` CSS properties so it's possible that Opera does the same (I don't really know).

However, there are possibly several browsers (not only Opera) that highlight remembered passwords this way (as well as focused items) and it's fairly difficult to keep track.

I think your best chance is to tweak your styling so it integrates better. Here's a example you can take as starting point:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head><title></title>
<style type="text/css"><!--
input{
    height: 38px;
    width: 284px;
    margin: 9px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #C7DDC8;
    background-color: #C7DDC8;
}
--></style>
</head>
<body>

<form action="" method="post">
    <p><input type="text" name="user"></p>
    <p><input type="password" name="password"></p>
    <p><button type="submit">Submit</button></p>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: Opera rendering]

Answer (score 0):

No. How would the user know that Opera remembers your password if you could remove the indication?

From your screen shot I guess your real problem is that this feature looks ugly given the way your inputs are styled - and I certainly agree with that. I guess you could file a complaint/bug at https://bugs.opera.com/wizard/ and explain what CSS is applied. I imagine for example Opera should make its future border-radius support affect the yellow wand border so that it can be curved if the site author so wishes.

Comment: I think the issue is that there is no border-radius but an outer `<div>` with a background image.